# How to view the contents or the changes done in a msu file

Tags: extract, hotfix

I got an hotfix from microsoft (msu file). How can i find the contents or the changes done in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Orca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx) - the MSI editor tool. It's part of the Windows Installer 5.0 SDK, which is included in the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en).

Comment: in my windowss 7 SDK i cannot find orca. Do i need to download in separately and install?

Comment: Orca.exe is not installed by default. Look for Orca.msi somewhere in teh Windows 7 SDK tree and run that installer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given solution, Orca cannot open a MSU file.
Orca always demands to open a msi or msp or psp file.

Currently, i think there is no such tool to open a MSU file.

If we want see the content inside, you can extract the MSU. Inside the extracted folder you will get Cab files and xml file